# IronWorker can't connect to my local mysql database

Tags: mysql, ironworker

It runs fine when I call `run_local`, but not when I call `queue`.

Comment: Is your DB available from internets at all?

Answer (score 2):

Is your MySQL database running on your machine? If you can't access it from the internet, IronWorker won't be able to connect to it.

You should either get a static IP for your machine or, what I'd recommend, host your database on a server made for web traffic. A lot of ISPs don't allow you to run web servers over domestic lines.

Besides local networking, however, everything that works in `run_local` should work in `queue`. If in doubt, you can check our [environment docs](http://dev.iron.io/worker/reference/environment).